# Docker with CUDA 11.7

Tags: docker, cuda, nvidia, nvidia-docker

Our current Docker definition of production environment starts like this

```
ARG CUDA="10.0"  
ARG CUDNN="7"
FROM nvidia/cuda:${CUDA}-cudnn${CUDNN}-devel-ubuntu18.04
```

I need to update the environment to use CUDA 11.7 and I tried to update the definition above to have

```
ARG CUDA="11.7"  
ARG CUDNN="8"
```

But I get the error:

`manifest for nvidia/cuda:11.7-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`

Any suggestions on how to build a Docker image with CUDA 11.7?

Answer (score 3):

FROM nvidia/cuda:11.7.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04